# TRIAC dimming using MOC3021 but light is flickering

Tags: microcontroller, pic, power-electronics, triac, component-selection

I m using a BTA12/BTA136/BTA139 for dimming using MOC3021 with zero cross detector circuit using interrupt pin of the controller, but after some time the light is flickering or the TRIAC is damaged.

What can I do to improve the circuit?

[image]

Comment: What's your load? _"BTA12/BTA136/BTA139"_ Which one? All three? What voltage is applied to LIGHT1 pin?

Comment: Dimming is properly work , but when multiple light is connected , light is flicker and off condition light is some blowing.

Comment: That answered none of my questions.

Answer (score 2):

R10 is probably too high at 470 ohms. Usually it is shown as being 220 when driven from 5V because you need to exceed the LED trigger current of 15mA. Since it has about 1.2V across it when on, R10 has to be less than (5-1.2)/0.015 = 253 ohms. But your micro might not drive all the way up to 5V even on a 5V supply or it might be 3V, you need to calculate based on what V output high minimum is. Even so, the micro might not be able to source 15mA.

(I've seen flickering on dimmers due to underdriven opto triac before, when the driving opamp was run from a 5V rail instead of a 12V one without changing the resistor).

[image: MOC3021 datasheet]

It's easy to misinterpret the fact that the 15mA LED trigger current is shown as a maximum. It's clearly nowhere near the maximum that is allowed, that is 60mA continuously, in the Maximum Ratings section. In this case it means that across component variations you will not find one that needs more than 15mA to guarantee that it turns on. Which means that is your *minimum* drive current.

Comment: I have changed the 220 ohm resistor but not changing anything ,

Comment: There is 1 or more light is attached  to dimming , that time flickering start , in one light does not flickering , is there any solution ? there is light is 30W and 25W light is attached , both are dimmable . is there any solutions?

Comment: is there any solutions ? @user263983

Answer (score 1):

I have an solution that stops the flickering. R9 is changed from 1K to 560 ohm 2watt. That stops the flickering and runs smoothly.

Comment: A somewhat larger value is recommended; mind the peak current rating of the MOC. Check the datasheet. 270-390 is a very typical value. Along with the R10 value change, that should solve things reliably.