# Triac dimming light is affected by other non dimmable load

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, triac, dimmer

When I am using one dimmable light turning on/off is working OK and dimmable is OK.
But when I’m using other non-dimmable load turn on/off, then dimmable light is on/off for the 1 s.

Is there any solution or suggestion needed?

I have attached the circuit used in zero cross detection and other.
If any changes required then suggest.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with the circuits you’ve shown? My guess is a microcontroller is involved and I’d be looking at the code. Also note there is no filtering on your zero cross signal and no snubber and choke on the triac circuit. As well, the word you want in your title is ‘affected’

Comment: Filtering on zero cross signal? can u suggest me the circuit ? @Kartman

Comment: One question at a time.

Comment: @Kartman He does say `if any changes required then suggest`. That might scrape by as a `suggestion question.` ;)

Comment: Please elaborate on _”dimmable light is on/off for the 1 s.”_.

Comment: When the other non dimmable light  is turned on and turned off that time , Dimmable light is flickered at that time .

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @the busybee I don't think that there is any Programming issue , Dimming is working properly , this problem is happen when other board light or fan is on , and our dimming light is on ,that time problem is occurred

Comment: Please add relevant information to your question by [edit]ing it, down here in the comments it is lost. Did you measure the control signal `TR1` of the microcontroller with an oscilloscope to be sure that it is not affected by switching the other load? Only then you can point at the circuit.

Comment: Sounds like leakage across your triac (snubber), causing low power LED lights to flicker, or sporadic triggering of your triac.

Comment: also I test that , When my Dimmable light is on , and other board which have fan , then I turned on/off the fan , my dimmable light is flickering , in on and off condition of the light . Is there any solution ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triac dimming using MOC3021 but light is flickering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651373/triac-dimming-using-moc3021-but-light-is-flickering)

Comment: yes that is also my question , This question in the past , i asked , in this flickering problem is solved

Comment: Now i m Trying Snubber circuit , With snubber circuit  , getting Problem solved that i asked . But Using snubber in off condition Light is Glow dim. Snubber Component Value - 39E - 2Watt & 0.01uF(10nf) 400V , If any one have solution For this snubber circuit ,